# Lots and lots of kernel log entries: iint_free: readcount: -1, iint_free: writecount: 1

Tags: linux, redhat

I am getting tons of log entries of the form

```
Mar  2 00:44:10 SRV123 kernel: iint_free: readcount: -1
Mar  2 00:44:10 SRV123 kernel: iint_free: writecount: 1
Mar  2 00:44:10 SRV123 kernel: iint_free: readcount: -4
Mar  2 00:44:10 SRV123 kernel: iint_free: writecount: 4
Mar  2 00:44:10 SRV123 kernel: iint_free: readcount: -2
Mar  2 00:44:10 SRV123 kernel: iint_free: writecount: 2
Mar  2 00:44:10 SRV123 kernel: iint_free: readcount: -1
Mar  2 00:44:10 SRV123 kernel: iint_free: writecount: 1
Mar  2 00:44:10 SRV123 kernel: iint_free: readcount: -1
Mar  2 00:44:10 SRV123 kernel: iint_free: writecount: 1
Mar  2 00:44:10 SRV123 kernel: iint_free: readcount: -1
Mar  2 00:44:10 SRV123 kernel: iint_free: writecount: 1
```

I have 8540 entries matching iint_free for March 2nd alone.

The readcount is always negative and the writecount is always readcount * -1. The values of readcount/writecount for March 2nd are in the range [-6490, -1]/[1, 6490], respectively.

One digit numbers are the more common ones, however:

```
  count  readcount
    754  -3
    586  -2
    454  -5
    332  -4
    210  -1
    163  -7
```

The server is a Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.8 (Tikanga)

Any idea what causes these messages? Can I somehow disable them?

Comment: Curious. I just stumbled across this via Google. On our FC12 (2.6.32.26 x86_64 kernel) server, we're getting the same thing. ~11000 of them since you asked this question. It's from the kernel itself and related to the `Integrity Measurement Architecture`. [This block of code contains the string in question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/linux.kernel/J7gxhLfARsY/0aJVgFAwn3cJ)